# Wrong status reason when importing

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm importing appointments and I get this error on all the instances.

> State code is invalid or state code is valid but status code is invalid for a specified state code.

According to the values suggested in the dropdown, *Completed* is OK to use. All my entries have that in the column for *StatusReason*. Should I force the numerical value as specified [here](http://mostlymscrm.blogspot.se/2012/06/entity-statecodes-and-statuscodes.html)?

How can I resolve this stupid issue?

Further on, CRM says that *3* isn't going to work.

> 3 is not a valid status code for state code AppointmentState.Open on appointment.

However, I can't specify that the appointment is closed, because there's no such column (for *Status* or *StateCode*). Weird... Shouldn't that be inferred from the value I specify?!

Comment: in which way is made this import? CRM UI, custom code, external tool?

Comment: CRM UI using Excel spreadsheet. I ended up changing all the statuses to *Free* but I don't like it. I want to import **closed** ones as closed...

Comment: You don't have a bad combination of status reason and state? StatusReason "OK" might be fine but not an option with statecode "inactive" or something like that. The statecode/statusreason are pretty tightly linked.

Comment: @RickardN I do. Hence the error. The problem is that on the empty Excel sheet that I downloaded for import, there's no column for both - just one of them (can't remember right now which one).

Comment: You should be able to get those fields in the template. Either by adding them to the form, export the template and then remove them from the form. You should alse be able to add columns to the template and then map them on import iirc.

Comment: Possibly a solution. When exporting the empty Excel sheet, I selected all the fields I could. Not sure if you can add **both** *StatusReason* **and** *StateCode* in the same import/export...

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar issue when we moved from Salesforce to CRM 2011. Going from memory, here are the steps I did:

1. Created a new custom field in the appointment entity called `ShouldBeClosed` - I just used a text field.
2. Updated my import sheet to have a value of `yes` for appointments which should be closed.
3. Imported the appointments using the open status (which is really all the importer will allow you to do).
4. Created a workflow to change the status of an appointment to the desired close state.
5. Ran an advanced find for all appointments where `ShouldBeClosed = yes` and on the results I ran the workflow created in the previous step.

Once finished, you can remove the `ShouldBeClosed` field and the workflow which closes the record

Comment: You HAVE got to be kidding! Seriously? I mean, I've seen a lot of weird hacks in CRM but still...   :)
(+1 for creativity, if not anything)

Comment: I have done similar to import things like closed Cases where the close action creates a Case Resolution activity. But for Appointments, I would suspect that the issue is that you need to specify both status and status reason at the same time, otherwise the new record will try to have an open status and conflicting status reason. If the columns are not in the template, just add them

Comment: CRM truly does test your creativity. It may not be pretty, but it worked well for a one-time process.